# MPAndroidChart Bar chart bar title rotation

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have problem with displaying of bars value. I want to display multiply bar chart, but when values are similar, then text is not very good readable :(.

[See picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TxGq.jpg)

Do you have some ideas for improving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you either develop some kind of mechanism that disables the drawing of values if they are too close to each other.

Other than that, you could:

- disable drawing the values in general
- reduce the text size drastically
- reduce the number of decimals
- use the `ValueFormatter` interface and disallow drawint 0 values